# Struts JQuery Tree - Not able to get the value of Multi selection

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

In Struts2 jQuery plugin, if i include `checkbox="true"` line in the below code, it is not calling the below jquery function `treeClicked`, But if remove that line(Single selection) we can able to call the jquery function, what code should be corrected below, in order to use multi selection option in Struts Jquery Tree.

```xml
<sjt:tree id="treeStatic" jstreetheme="apple" openAllOnLoad="true" 
                onClickTopics="treeClicked"
                checkbox="true"
                checkboxCheckAllTopics="checkAllNodesTopic"
                checkboxUncheckAllTopics="uncheckAllNodesTopic"
                checkboxShowTopics="showCheckboxesTopic"
                checkboxHideTopics="hideCheckboxesTopic">
                    <sjt:treeItem title="Alphabet">
                        <sjt:treeItem title="A"/>
                        <sjt:treeItem title="B"/>
                        <sjt:treeItem title="C"/>
                        <sjt:treeItem title="D"/>
                </sjt:treeItem>
            </sjt:tree>
```

```javascript
$.subscribe('treeClicked', function (event, data){
    var item = event.originalEvent.data.rslt.obj;
    alert(item.text().trim());
});
```